# Minecraft - How do you make blocks disappear when you go near them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know how to make it so that when you go near a certain block that block will disappear. I'm also looking for something where the command block **is not** where the disappearing block will go. What is the command to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a command block testing for a player within a certain radius from the block coords:

```
/testfor @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R]
```

*(Where X Y Z are the coordinates of the block you want to disappear, and R is the distance you want it to disappear from)*

Then have a comparator on that leading directly to a command block removing the you want to disappear:

```
/setblock X Y Z air
```

*(Again, where X Y Z are the coordinates of the block you want to disappear.)*

You could also simplify this down into one command like this:

```
/execute @a[X,Y,Z,R] ~ ~ ~ /setblock X Y Z air
```